# Custom Object created not seen in the DashBoard in quickblox.?

Tags: ios, quickblox

```
 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 356;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Tue, 24 Nov 2015 11:46:20 GMT";
Etag = "\"bf1976302fa3e0bdcab3fa649f59876e\"";
Location = "https://api.quickblox.com/users/7083904";
"QB-Token-ExpirationDate" = "2015-11-24 13:46:19 UTC";
"QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
Status = "201 Created";
"Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=15768000;";
"X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
"X-Request-Id" = 4397338ed3888b7fe46809adc01b5a7f;
"X-Runtime" = "0.041577";
"X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
```

Custom object is created but not seen in dashboard of quickblox. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

First you should create class (schema) with fields that you need to be filled.